# In the last scene of the Silicon Valley finale, whose photo is in Richard's office?

Tags: silicon-valley

At the end of Silicon Valley S06E07, Richard is interviewed in his office. Behind him, on the whiteboard, there is a signed photo of a guy, slightly out of focus. Who is that person?

[image]

Comment: A screen-cap of the scene would definitely help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guy in that portrait is [David Huffman](https://www.computerhope.com/people/david_huffman.htm).

[image]

He seems to be Richard's role model as he was pioneering computer scientist who worked in developing compression algorithms. Richard has mentioned earlier in his Tech Crunch talk too.

[image]